# systemd syntax variations and differences

Tags: systemd, nginx

Upon getting this type of error:

```
nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Mon 2022-09-26 22:17:21 UTC; 8h ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
```

there was an attempt to monitor and restart nginx when it would fail.  Yet, different syntassi are proposed in various sources:

```
Restart=always
Restart=on-failure
```

The documentation for either the [timers](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html) or the [units](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#) do not describe this parameter.  Which also creates uncertainty as to what is the default timer and whether it should be specifically set.

The `nginx.service` file was edited to include one, then the other from directory `/usr/lib/systemd/system`.
*Interestingly, directory `/lib/systemd/system` has the same file (and neither is indicated as an alias; I assume a directory alias is in play?) and a change to one is reflected on the other.*
All changes were followed up by a `systemctl daemon-reload`

The change did not restart nginx as expected. Thus:

- what is the difference between these two syntassi
- what timer is applied by default if none is specified

Comment: "Interestingly, directory /lib/systemd/system has the same file" Look up "usr merge": https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/ https://wiki.debian.org/UsrMerge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s an index for all systemd directives in [`man systemd.directives`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.directives.html); for `Restart=`, this leads to [`man systemd.service`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=).

`Restart=` determines what should happen when the managed service exits. `on-failure` specifies that it should be restarted if it exits with a non-zero exit code, because of a signal, or if a management operation times out. `always` specifies that it should be restarted in all cases.

There is no monitoring timeout here, the process is restarted when it exits. Services can be configured with a watchdog, but that requires cooperation from the managed service (it needs to periodically notify the watchdog).