# systemd configuration reset?

Tags: systemd, nginx

Having already queried on the [matter of syntax](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/718868/systemd-syntax-variations-and-differences) for restarting a server and having modified `nginx.service` by adding `Restart=always` for a few servers, a few weeks later I find the configuration file is devoid of this option.

Could I possibly have misconfigured the option in the wrong block (`[Service]`)  or is there a mechanism by which this file is overwritten and reset to a default state?

What is a sound approach to monitoring this situation, as one of the servers nginx has decided to fall over frequently (possibly daily - a suspect is letsencrypt renewal verifications process) ?

```
[Unit]
Description=A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
Documentation=man:nginx(8)
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;' -s reload
ExecStop=-/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid
TimeoutStopSec=5
KillMode=mixed

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Which file did you modify — the file in `/lib` (or `/usr/lib`), or the file in `/etc`?

Comment: definitely not `/etc` .  I do not recall which of  `/usr/lib` of `/lib` but had noticed they were symlinked.  Just checked: directory `/etc/systemd/system` has no reference to `nginx.service` in either of the servers

Comment: Got the answer and am implementing. Is the position of the option in a given block relevant?

Comment: Not for `Restart=`, but why is that a concern? Your override file should only have `[Service]` followed by `Restart=…`. (Incidentally, if you have a comment on an answer, you should comment on the answer; I only got notified of your comment in this instance because I’d commented on the question myself.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files under `/lib` or `/usr/lib` “belong” to the system’s package management system and must not be modified; package updates will overwrite your changes. This is likely what happened here.

You should add your specific settings in snippets, using `systemctl edit`; see [How can I make a modification to a .service and keep it persistent?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/418820/86440) for details.

Comment: [got it!]  Maybe I misinterpreted the docs.  I considered the two avenues, possibly mistakenly, and decided on wanting to see all the vendor settings & editing from that. I thus copied the file and edited that.  Pitfalls in this approach?

Comment: Copying the complete file means the unit is entirely overridden, which means you won’t get any improvements made to the unit file in the package.